# easiest way to bundle prod build as stand alone self serve

Tags: angular, devops

When we are in dev mode we simply do `ng serve` which serves the app, but when you do `build --prod` it just bundle the app but there is no way to serve that bundle on it is own. You are expected put it in some server.
How can I create a stand alone bundle that also serves my application.
The main reason is to make it easy to work with Bamboo, Artifactory, Mesos stack.
Current solution is to run a script in bamboo with the following steps:

1. ng build --prod
2. download and unzip nginx from Artifactory
3. Copying ng dist to nginx
4. zipping nginx back and publishing

can we avoid this and get a stand alone package in a simpler way ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way around running a web server if you want to host your app.

You can use an npm package called http-sever to do this. It's probably easier than the nginx thing you're doing.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server